# Appropriate application of null model simulation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, simulation

I have a question regarding the appropriate use/application of a null model simulation. The structure of the study is:
-60 pairs (120 total) of nest boxes
-surveyed five time per year (April, June, July, August, October)
-surveyed for five years

I want to statistically assess the differences between sample month. Specifically, occupancy appears consistently higher in particular months, regardless of year. Because this is a repeated measures scenario, something like a Kruskal-Wallis test seems inappropriate (the samples are not independent across years).

I was thinking of building a null model to simulate expected occupancy, given the existing frequency distribution in the real data, and assuming random assignment of individuals to boxes. Is that an appropriate use of a null model?

Comment: (1) Chances are you won't have independence between different months, which will cause complication. (2) Chances are if you want to model this realistically, quite a bit of subject matter specialist knowledge is needed. Maybe collaborate with a statistician in presence. (3) Is the idea that on average all months are the same any realistic or is it crystal clear (from existing knowledge) that systematic differences will exist?

Comment: (4) No test that is constructed after seeing the data, conditionally on the data,  to show that what you saw is significant will be valid, unless you would've wanted to test the same thing before you had seen the data. Or you test on new independent data.

Comment: Thanks Christian. The null assumption would be that there are no differences between samples or years. This was the assumption prior to the study. The months and years will not be independent. The null model we would build would replicate the entire sample (all months an years as a single simulated block). Thanks.